# Load a swf on Mouse click event in another swf

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, adobe, flash-cs6

I have multiple swf files where the first swf file represents an Introduction to my app and in this file I will have multiple buttons, I want button 1 to load another swf file and in the loaded movie I will have a home button to get me back to the first swf. 
I was trying to do so but still unable to. 
This is the code I wrote so far.

```
import flash.display.Loader;
import flash.net.URLRequest;

 stop();

var AlphabetsLoader:Loader = new Loader();
Alphabets_Gate.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, AlphabetsSWF);


function AlphabetsSWF(event:MouseEvent):void
  {
    var AlphabetRequest: URLRequest= new URLRequest("AlphabetsGate.swf");
    AlphabetsLoader.load(AlphabetRequest);
    stage.addChild(AlphabetsLoader);

  }
```

I have imported the swf to be loaded in the library. Also, I have put it in the same folder where the .fla file exists because I wasn't sure.

I get an Error msg saying:

> VerifyError: Error #1053: Illegal override of createGeometry in flashx.textLayout.elements.FlowGroupElement.
>   ReferenceError: Error #1065: Variable _11f1d66f38eb234da07a684678bb07c1e6cff9d15441f91af33073b7534701e8_flash_display_Sprite is not defined.

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment so I'll just answer here.

If you want to load external swf into your own swf, you'll need to use `SWFLoader`

I answered more briefly here: [Actionscript 3 - List error when loading another a swf in my swf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23304899/actionscript-3-list-error-when-loading-another-a-swf-in-my-swf/23361092#23361092)